# regex not work correctly on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, keypress

I want to prevent users from using letter keys on input
and i use following code in jquery

```
var enK = /^(6[5-9])|([7-9][0-9])|(1([01][0-9]|2[0-2]))$/y;
// this regex is for event code of a-z and A-Z letters in keypress event
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').bind('keypress',function(evt){
        var evC = evt.which || evt.charCode;
        if(enK.test(evC)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

Test1 :

Input keys : abcdefg

Output : bdf

Test2 :

Input keys : aaaaaa

Output : aaa

These tests means that :

-First keypress is prevented

-Second keypress not match to regex and will not prevented

-Third keypress is prevented

-Fourth keypress not match to regex and will not prevented

...

following code has same resualt.

```
var enC = /[a-z|A-Z]/g;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').bind('keypress',function(evt){
        var evC =  evt.which || evt.charCode;
        evC = String.fromCharCode(evC);
        if(enC.test(evC)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

Now how should i solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: Your regex isn't doing anything close to checking for any letters. I don't have a clue what you are trying to do here based on what you provided.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it checks for the keycode. `a` = 97, etc.

Comment: @Jorg Wouldn't it be easier to just check the value rather than the keycodes? Regex isn't really good for number ranges.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Convert it to a character: `String.fromCharCode(evC)` and then just check `/[a-z]/i`.

Comment: @Jorg i use String.fromCharCode(evC) too. but the resualt not changed.

Comment: @hadikarami - remove the `y` from the end of your regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').bind('keypress',function(evt){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.charCode);
    if(/[a-z]/i.test(key) === false) evt.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

This prevents all input except a-z and A-Z.

https://jsfiddle.net/0b2f7wyL/1/

@fubar in the comments had the right answer: the `y` is the 'Sticky' flag, it tells the regular expression to look for a match at lastIndex and only at lastIndex (not earlier or later in the string), which is why ever other check failed.